# create an ID column by its natural order

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this

```
df=data.frame(subject= c(rep(1001, 3), rep(732, 2),rep(966,4)))
```

I wish to create an ID column so that the output could look like this

```
  subject id
1    1001  1
2    1001  1
3    1001  1
4     732  2
5     732  2
6     966  3
7     966  3
8     966  3
9     966  3
```

I used the code `df$id <- as.numeric(as.factor(df$subject))` , but it gave me an id column ordered by the subject number like this

```
  subject id
1    1001  3
2    1001  3
3    1001  3
4     732  1
5     732  1
6     966  2
7     966  2
8     966  2
9     966  2
```

does anyone know how to make the id column with its natural order?

Comment: `df$id <- with(df, as.numeric(factor(subject, levels = unique(subject))))`

Comment: I always find `rle` useful for this kind of thing.... `r <- rle(df$subject); rep(seq_along(r$values),r$lengths)`

Comment: @rawr, why do you so often answer questions as a comment and not write a full answer? I see you do this a lot (700+ comments for only 75 answers) and I find it a bit counter productive for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Simply coping  [rawr's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150081/create-an-id-column-by-its-natural-order#comment39151958_25150081) to get the question closed (I'm happy to delete this answer if  rawr post an answer)

```
df=data.frame(subject= c(rep(1001, 3), rep(732, 2),rep(966,4)))
df
  subject id
1    1001  1
2    1001  1
3    1001  1
4     732  2
5     732  2
6     966  3
7     966  3
8     966  3
9     966  3
```

Comment: +1 have some credit for taking the time to answer. And for attributing the source of your answer.